# using Directory Name as input to Stored procedure in batch script

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file

-I have created one batch file which takes path to a folder as input parameter. Now i want to Use this again as the inout parameter for the Stored procedure which i am executing through the batch file. Kindly let me know as i am stuck on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think i understand you clearly. Can you show us some code or explain with examples?

Comment: We will need a little bit of code to see.  You can refer to input parameters in batch files using %1 %2, etc.

Comment: How are you getting the input parameter? %1,%2?  Set/p? another variable?

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
@echo off
set /p "$path=Enter the Path :"
echo the path : "%$path%" is in the variable %%$path%%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . this is working exactly the way i was looking for.